# Want to create a group within the data in sql

Tags: sql, hive

We have data from agents login and logout activity.  We want to show the login time as the reporting date for a login that happened yesterday and a logout that happened today.

Initial Column Names: AgentNumber, ActivityDate, Activity(login/logout), Time

```
Agent1, 20-oct, login, 12:00pm
Agent1, 20-0ct, away, 4:00pm
Agent1, 20-0ct, logout, 6:00pm
Agent1, 20-oct, login, 10:00pm
Agent1, 21-oct, away, 12:00Am
Agent1, 21-oct, logout ,4:00Am
```

Required output column Names: AgentNumber, ActivityDate, Activity(login/logout), Time, GroupNumber

```
Agent1, 20-oct, login, 12:00pm, group1
Agent1, 20-0ct away ,4:00pm ,group1
Agent1, 20-Oct, logout, 6:00pm ,group1
Agent1, 20-oct, login, 10:00pm, group2,
Agent1, 21-oct, away, 12:00Am, group2
Agent1, 21-oct, logout, 4:00am, group2
```

We want to calculate logout-login and report the data for 20-October though the logout falls on the next day

So between every login and logout we want to form a group ,how to assign same value for a group  from login and logout,so that we can report the login hours for 20-oct.

We want only SQL to achieve this.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Yeah some additional Infos would be good, like what have you tried and what isn't working, maybe even your error. Also, I can't see the exact question here.

Comment: DBMS is hive sql

Comment: Please show the *results* that you want.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's better for people trying to help you if you edit your question to make it more clear, rather than posting comments yourself. I would recommend reading the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for tips on asking good questions which people will be able and willing to answer for you. Also, the page on [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is very helpful.

Comment: I just need a groupcolumn to be added to the input as group1,group2.Above is the expected result

Answer (score 0):

The below query should get you going.  If you have more than two groups you can amend the case statement to include as many as you need.

```
SELECT
     AgentNumber
    ,ActivityDate
    ,Activity
    ,Time
    CASE
        WHEN AgentNumber = Agent1 THEN Group1
        WHEN AgentNumber = Agent2 THEN Group2
        ELSE OtherGroup
    END AS GroupNumber
FROM AgentActivityTable1
WHERE ActivityDate >= '2018-10-20'
```

Comment: It is one agent having multiple logins.i have just corrected the output required.one agent has multiple login and logout